# Changing element Id at run time Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying  to change element `(anchor tag)` `id` in run time using Jquery but unable to get any success so far.

this is my anchor tag code

```
<a id="addToCartButton_${idStatus}" href="javascript://"
 onclick="addTocartFunction(${idStatus})" class="button"
  type="submit">ADD TO CART</a>
```

I tried following approach

```
$("addToCartButton_"+id).attr('id','addToCartButton_'+code);
```

where `id` is same as `idStatus` but nothing was happening
than I tried to check if Jquery even able to find element with given Id so I tried following code

`alert($("addToCartButton_"+id).attr('href'))` but it is coming as `undefined`. I am not sure where I am doing wrong

Comment: what is the id of a tag after rendering on page

Comment: It's because the jQuery selector is incorrect. It should be `$("#addToCartButton_"+id)`

Comment: Try never to use "${}" symbol in the ID.

Comment: @ManishPatwari - It looks like `${idStatus}` will be replaced with the value of `idStatus`, and not literally as `"${idStatus}"`

Comment: I would suggest using the [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug) or [Chrome Developer Toolbar](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) Using the Console type in your selector $("#addToCartButton_5") as an example, and run that code to see if it matches any elements. The Developer tool bars are very useful for testing Javascript code before you put it in your JS files.

Comment: **id="addToCartButton_${idStatus}"** means a string. So, I thought he is using this symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ID selector is incorrect. Right now it will look for elements with the tagname as `"addToCartButton_"+id`. If id is `5`, it would look for elements like `<addToCartButton_5>...</addToCartButton_5>`

It should instead be:

```
$("#addToCartButton_"+id).attr('id','addToCartButton_'+code); 
   ^ ID selector
```

Comment: @techfoobar: Thing is I am quite ok with Jquery but was so confused as never looked at `#`

Comment: Happens to everyone.. Glad my answer helped.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the the `#` to select the element by id (assume you've forgot):  `$("#addToCartButton_"+id).attr('id','addToCartButton_'+code);`

And here:

```
alert($("#addToCartButton_"+id).attr('href'))
```

which may have prevented it from appearing in the alert dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `#` in your code `$("addToCartButton_"+id)`